# Tank Auth login successful on local, fails on server

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, tankauth

I am using Tank Auth for Codeigniter to facilitate user registration and login.

**Problem:** I am able to login perfectly using tank auth on my local Windows development server (XAMPP). However when I copied the entire database and entire directory structure to my remote server, updated `config/config.php` and `config/database.php` with my remote server details, I can no longer login with Tank Auth! The error given is an `incorrect password`. Using PHPMyAdmin, I resetted the password using the `MD5()` function but I still cannot login.

Any idea what went wrong, or how you manage to solve it?

**EDIT:** IF I **register a new user** on the remote site, its login will work!! I still need to know how to solve this problem as I may be changing servers soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Tank Auth uses phpass, you'll need to make the hash portable. In your Codeigniter project, go to application > config > tank_auth.php and on line 22, change the following boolean to TRUE (I think by default it's set to FALSE).

```
$config['phpass_hash_portable'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 3):

I never used it, but IIRC Tank Auth uses [**phpass**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) to hash the password, which make it difficult to be portable.

Using md5() as you did is useless and against the purposes behind Tank Auth!

A solution could be to retrieve the original infos: download a new package, copy the default admin data and use the library's methods to generate your new password.

Comment: Yes I saw the phpass library inside the Tank Auth files. Anyway to make the files portable?

Comment: I dont quite get it, what new package do I download, what is the admin data, and how do I regenerate the hashed passwords if the original passwords are already hashed.

Comment: Sorry, I see now that Tank Auth does only install the database schema. What did you do the first time you used it? You can, once everything is uploaded, delete the admin user and create another anew as if it were the first installation on your local machine

Comment: Tank Auth provided a SQL file that created the relevant tables for me. I ran that file when installing Tank Auth. If I already have 1000 users on the site using tank auth, and I want to change to another server, I am worried that it'll be a nightmare if all users' passwords no longer work!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and had exactly the same tankauth on a different site that worked fine. The problem was that the site that it didn't work on had the .htacces file from html5 boilerplate, which tank auth didnt seem to like aparantly. I removed that file and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup. The site that tank_auth didnt work on did not use html5 boilerplate. I have since moved to a new PHP framework with an authentication library built in. Will be rewriting my older site using the new framework.